# FromBody returns data as null after adding JsonSerializer converters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I added the following converters in .Net 6 Startup like below:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverterFactory());
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DecimalConverterFactory());
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new IntConverterFactory());
        });
```

After adding these converters, whenever I pass data from ajax javascript like below. I am getting null in controller method. If I comment out these converters, the code works. Kindly suggest.

```
function PerformAction(url, data) {
    var model = {}; //pass all the data to an object
    model.ListOfIds = data;

    var testModel = JSON.stringify(model);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        Traditional: true,
        data: testModel,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (ValidationErrors) {
            // some work here
        }
    });
}
```

The controller side:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AjaxReject([FromBody] ListModel testModel)
{
    var listOfIds = testModel?.ListOfIds; // testModel is null and ListOfIds is null
}

public class ListModel
{
    public List<int> ListOfIds { get; set; }
}
```

One of the convertors:

```
public class DecimalConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(decimal) ||
            typeToConvert == typeof(decimal?);
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //You may be tempted to cache these converter objects. 
        //Don't. JsonSerializer caches them already.
        if (typeToConvert == typeof(decimal))
        {
            return new DecimalConverter();
        }
        else if (typeToConvert == typeof(decimal?))
        {
            return new NullableDecimalConverter();
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("CreateConverter got called on a type that this converter factory doesn't support");
    }
}

public class DecimalConverter : JsonConverter<decimal>
{
    public override decimal Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var decimalToParse = reader.GetString();
        return DecimalExtensions.GetFormattedDecimal(decimalToParse);
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        decimal objectToWrite,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(objectToWrite.ToString());
    }
}

public class NullableDecimalConverter : JsonConverter<decimal?>
{
    public override decimal? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.GetString() is { } value)
        {
            return DecimalExtensions.GetFormattedDecimal(value);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        decimal? objectToWrite,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (objectToWrite is { })
            writer.WriteRawValue(objectToWrite.ToString());
        else writer.WriteNullValue();
    }
}
```

IntConvertorFavtory:

```
public class IntConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(int) ||
            typeToConvert == typeof(int?);
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //You may be tempted to cache these converter objects. 
        //Don't. JsonSerializer caches them already.
        if (typeToConvert == typeof(int))
        {
            return new IntConverter();
        }
        else if (typeToConvert == typeof(int?))
        {
            return new NullableIntConverter();
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("CreateConverter got called on a type that this converter factory doesn't support");
    }
}

public class IntConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var stringValue = reader.GetString();
        return IntExtensions.GetFormattedInt(stringValue);
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        int objectToWrite,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteNumberValue(objectToWrite);
    }
}

public class NullableIntConverter : JsonConverter<int?>
{
    public override int? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.GetString() is { } value)
        {
            return IntExtensions.GetFormattedInt(value);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        int? objectToWrite,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (objectToWrite is { })
            writer.WriteNumberValue((int)objectToWrite);
        else writer.WriteNullValue();
    }
}
```

DecimalConvertorFactory:

```
public class DecimalConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(decimal) ||
            typeToConvert == typeof(decimal?);
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //You may be tempted to cache these converter objects. 
        //Don't. JsonSerializer caches them already.
        if (typeToConvert == typeof(decimal))
        {
            return new DecimalConverter();
        }
        else if (typeToConvert == typeof(decimal?))
        {
            return new NullableDecimalConverter();
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("CreateConverter got called on a type that this converter factory doesn't support");
    }
}

public class DecimalConverter : JsonConverter<decimal>
{
    public override decimal Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var decimalToParse = reader.GetString();
        return DecimalExtensions.GetFormattedDecimal(decimalToParse);
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        decimal objectToWrite,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(objectToWrite.ToString());
    }
}

public class NullableDecimalConverter : JsonConverter<decimal?>
{
    public override decimal? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.GetString() is { } value)
        {
            return DecimalExtensions.GetFormattedDecimal(value);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        decimal? objectToWrite,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (objectToWrite is { })
            writer.WriteRawValue(objectToWrite.ToString());
        else writer.WriteNullValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console? Are there any errors?

Comment: no errors. if i comment the convertors, the testModel populates and ListOfIds are there. after adding covertors, I get null in testModel. Somehow convertors are messing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After adding these converters, whenever I pass data from ajax
> javascript like below. I am getting null in Controller. If I comment
> these converters, the code works. Kindly suggest.

Well, you are getting null value because fo your incorrect model bindings. You have defined as `model` but in your controller parameter defined as `testModel` so when you have `JSON.stringify(model)` it already parsed into `model` not int `testModel`. Therefore, you are getting null.

**Solution:**

Based on your C# POCO you should bind your Javascript model  as following:

```
           var ListOfIds = [1, 2, 3];
           
            var testModel = {};

            testModel.ListOfIds = ListOfIds;

            console.log(testModel);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AjaxPostNull/AjaxReject",
                type: "POST",
                Traditional: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(testModel),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (ValidationErrors) {
                    // some work here
                }
            });
```

[image]

**Note:** Point to consider here `var testModel = JSON.stringify(model)` it's model key will still be treated as `model` which is certainly mismatched with controller parameter defined as `testModel` so you have to bind as `testModel.ListOfIds`

**Output:**

[image]

**Update:**

I have reeproduced your issue successfully, as per my investigation, your `public override int Read` extension method within `public class IntConverter : JsonConverter<int>` causing your null values on controller as its encountered an runtimee excption. As you can see following:

[image]

As you can see, `Token Type` is a type of `Number` but you are trying to unbox it by `reader.GetString()` which throws the exception. I am not quite sure what it does. Thus, based on the defination I have replaced it based on its data type as following:

```
public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        try
        {
          //  var stringValue = reader.GetString();
            var stringValue = reader.ValueSequence;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
       
        //return IntExtensions.GetFormattedInt(stringValue);
        return 0;
    }
```

**Note:** Above changes resolved throwing exception but I am not sure, what you were intended to return here. Now, your controller getting value and issue has been resolved. Furthermore, I would suggeest your to apply your necessary changes here. This is the scenario getting null value for your `AddJsonOptions`. Regardless of your implementation, I have observed, this costing a huge runtime performence issue on application memory.

Comment: Okay, I will double check meanwhile, You can see my debugger result.

Comment: yes i am having the debugger console data. Can you please test with one of the convertors I have created and see if u get the same error.

Comment: Well, could you please share few more details about `IntConverterFactory()` and other converter. Or which package have your ingerated?

Comment: Sure, thanks for shareing, let me have a look.

Comment: Another issue, what package did you used here `IntExtensions.GetFormattedInt` I am getting compilation error.

Comment: Please have look on the upated answer on **Update** part. Thanks